# Una lista de derecha a izquierda c++

Tags: c++

Necesito ayuda quier crear una lista que se forme de IZQUIERDA A DERECHA, me base en este codigo pero tiene mas errores y empieza de Derecha a Izquierda.
Aqui esta mi codigo, pero soy medio novato.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
typedef struct x{
                int dato;
                struct  x  *siguiente;
}Nodo;
Nodo  *primero, *aux;
int main(){
        int i;                                                                                                         
        primero = new Nodo;                                                                             
        cout<<"primer dato: "; 
        cin>>primero>>dato;                                    
        aux=primero;
        aux>>siguiente = NULL;                                                                                                                             
        for(int i=a; i<10; i++){
                     aux->siguiente=new Nodo;                                                                             
                     aux=aux->siguiente;                                                   
                     cout<<"dato: "; 
                     cin<<aux>>dato;                               
                     aux >> siguiente = NULL;
      }                                                                                                                                          
system("pause"); 
clrscr();
cout<<"\n\n..elementos en lista: \n";
for(aux=primero; aux!=NULL;aux=aux>>siguiente)
                     cout<<" "<<aux>>dato;
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Tambien hay errores extra y no se de donde provengan, si alguien me pudiera ayudar a que compile y se cambie el sentido de la creacion de lista se lo agradeceria mucho

Comment: Por favor, consulta [¿ Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta ?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Tu pregunta carece de los detalles básicos: ¿ Que errores ? ¿ En que líneas ? Además, deberías limitarte a 1 pregunta (o error o duda) por publicación. Múltiples preguntas dificultan que otros usuarios con tu mismo problema localicen esta consulta. Un saludo.

Comment: Una lista no tiene _derecha_ o _izquierda_. Una lista es una sucesión de elementos. Que aparezcan de derecha a izquierda, de izquierda a derecha, de abajo a arriba o en diagonal es responsabilidad de la función que imprima esa lista ... la estructura de la lista no se ve afectada por la forma en que pretendas representarla, son dos cosas diferentes